# Need to pass text box values as parameters when calling controller method on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm working on an MVC form that's supposed to let the user enter some descriptions of their problem in various fields, and the text in those fields will then be compiled into an email and sent to us after the user clicks the "Submit" button.

I've got enough wired up to pass hardcoded strings as parameters when the user clicks the button.

```
@model IntakeFormV2.Models.BotRequest
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<style type="text/css">
    #textarea {
        height: 500px;
    }
</style>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" asp-controller="HomeController" asp-action="Create">

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>New Request</legend>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Summarize your issue in 100 characters</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="textinput" name="title" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Textarea -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textarea">Let us know about any additional information here</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea1" name="description"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <p>@Html.ActionLink("Submit Request", "Create", "Home", routeValues: new { title = "hello", description = "world" }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "btn btn-primary"})</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

But rather than passing "Hello" and "World", I need to pass whatever the user inputs into the "textinput" and "textarea1" fields.

I'm fairly new at MVC, but I know the model is supposed to be involved here somewhere. But I haven't been able to find how to set the model values from the view once there's actually text in the input.

```
namespace RPAIntakeFormV2.Models
{
    public class BotRequest
    {
        public string RequestTitle { get; set; }
        public string RequestDescription { get; set; }
        public string RequesterName { get; set; }
        public string RequesterDepartment { get; set; }
        private bool RequestAdded = false;
    }
}
```

And here's my controller, broadly speaking - I've held off adding a lot of the intended functionality until I can actually get the parameters I need in there.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IEnumerable<IssuePriority> priorities;
    private IEnumerable<IssueStatus> statusses;

    public HomeController()
    {
        index i = 1;
    }

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Create(string title, string description)
    {
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello world");

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return View("Index2");
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: Show us your controller

Comment: Edited to add controller code - as I said, it's pretty bare-bones at the moment, but I have confirmed I'm at least able to get the hardcoded strings passed into the Create method as parameters.

Comment: You should use Razor Helpers (@Html.xxx) instead of html controls (inputs, textarea's, ...), bind your model to it (if BotRequest is your model, bind that), than you can pass your Model as a parameter in your Controller's Create method.

Comment: We actually are binding to a model currently. I had to cut out some commented out text at the top and accidentally cut that out as well - have edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you set name for input tag and textarea **same with your parameter** in action so that you can add `action="/Home/Create"` to form and change action link to `<button>` tag or `<input type="submit" />` tag like this

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="/Home/Create">

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <fieldset>

        <!-- Form Name -->
        <legend>New Request</legend>

        <!-- Text input-->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Summarize your issue in 100 characters</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="textinput" name="title" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Textarea -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textarea">Let us know about any additional information here</label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="textarea1" name="description"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Button -->
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="singlebutton"></label>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <button>Submit Request</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

If you have two Create method, you need mark HttpPost attribute

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string title, string description)
```

Comment: Just the one Create method at the moment, but I'll keep that in mind if we need another. Otherwise, these changes did the trick, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your form is type of `Post` then your controller action method should be `[HttpPost]` your "hello" and "world" is works because of you send this in your query parameter and it consider as `[HttpGET]`

so first if you require to submit form then your button should be input type of `SUBMIT`
rather than `actionlink` use input type submit

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit Request" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

if you are used `asp.net core` then

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" asp-controller="HomeController" asp-action="Create">
```

HERE `asp-controller` and `asp-action` is asp.net core taghelpers.

your form action was consider as `Home/Create` just use controller as `Home`

and if you are using `MVC 4` as you **tag** in `MVC-4` taghelpers is not supported.
for `MVC-4` you should used like

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("create", "home", FormMethod.Post))
{

}
```

then issue with your code is set your action in form and set `[HttpPost]` attribute on your action method.

and your action should be like below

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string title, string description)
{
     //----
}
```

and your HTML `textbox` name must be same as your model Property which you want bind. or you can use `@Html.TextBoxFor()`

like example

let me know if you require more information.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
     <input id="textinput" name="RequestTitle" type="text" class="form-control input-md" required="" />
</div>
```

now `id="textinput"` is bind with your model property `RequestTitle`